# How would one reset the page options of a table in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

While I am in page `2` of my pagination

[image]

My options look like this

[image]

Then, I create a record that required me to call API to updateData() on the table.

I would like to reset my pagination back to the first page.

I've tried

```
this.options = {}
```

I have this codes

```
watch: {
    options: {
        handler() {
            this.getData(this.options)
        },
        deep: true
    }
},
```

Any hints for me ?

Comment: You can force the component re-render by using a `key` attribute. For ex, `:key="X"`  make it rerender by changing the `X`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the `options` prop of `v-data-table`, you can just set the page back to 1.

```
methods: {
  goToFirstPage() {
    this.$set(this.options, 'page', 1);
  }
}
```

If not, add a `page` data and bind it to the data table so you can easily change the page.

```
<v-data-table :page="page" />
```

```
data: () => ({
   page: 1,
}),

methods: {
  goToFirstPage() {
    this.page = 1;
  }
}
```